# Is there a way to create a symlink to a non-existent target?

Tags: shell-script, symlink, ln

Is there a way to create a *symlink* whose target does not exist using shell scripts?

From reading **`man 1 ln`**, I do not see an option to do so; and even `-f` checks if the target exists.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you run

```
ln -s nonexistenttarget link
```

`ln` doesn’t check whether `nonexistenttarget` exists, it creates the link, unless `link` already exists. `-f` works around the last part by deleting `link` if necessary.

The impact of a non-existent target is only felt when a program tries to dereference the link, *e.g.* by opening it:

```
$ ls -l link
lrwxrwxrwx 1 steve steve 17 May 22 08:44 link -> nonexistenttarget

$ cat link
cat: link: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I once saw a script here somewhere (can't find it now) that created symbolic links that contained the text of a shell script, by mistake (wrong variable used in `ln -s` command).